# Beginners qestion: How to import / access a .NET assembly from a Visual Studio 2008 C++ ATL project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dllimport, atl

I'm just taking my first steps in the Visual Studio 2008 / C++ world, and I do so by trying to create a new CTI Connector for Salesforce. I managed the first part without too much hassle, so now I have an almost-functional CTI Connector. There's only one, but vital part missing: The actual connection to the Call Center system.

The manufacturer provides a .NET integration DLL that also provides a COM interface. I've successfully used the COM part before in Delphi (my native environment...) and I wouldn't mind to use the COM approach here as well, though using the .NET interface seems a bit more natural to me.

Now I do have an ATL project created in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, providing a COM interface to the Salesforce side of the connection.

I do also have a .NET dll providing the interface to the Call Center, and a registered COM object that does the same.

What I *don't* have is the slightest idea how to get this into my C++ project.

From my Delphi experience I was expecting Visual Studio to have some Import feature that automagically builds a class around the integration object in order for me to simply use it, but obviously there isn't, at least not for ATL projects. Changing the project type to something else is currently not an option, as this is the documented way to interface Salesforce.

I found some hints to simply include the .tlb in a .cpp file in order to use the COM object, and doing so does indeed help IntelliSense to recognize the Namespace and Classes of this object, but this is where I'm stuck.

So my qustions are:

- Am I required to create the methods and events provided by the .NET dll / COM object manually, or is there a simpler way to get them automatically?
- If manual creation is required, how do I access the Event interface of the integration object?
- How do instantiate the integration object, and do I have to do so at all?

Until now, I've created a class called CAgentIntegration. In the .cpp file I import the typelib provided with the DLL (AgentIntegration.dll and AgentIntegration.tlb), both files are present in the source folder of my project.

In the constructor of CAgentIntegration, I try to somehow access the imported object. IntelliSense obviously recognizes the Namespace `AgentIntegration`, because it offers the `AgentClient` class as code completion. It is the part after `AgentClient` of which I have no idea. The example below clearly doesn't work because the compiler complains that to the left of `->` a class or struct is required.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"

#import "AgentIntegration.tlb"

CAgentIntegration::CAgentIntegration(void)
{
    AgentIntegration::AgentClient->Initialize();
}

CAgentIntegration::~CAgentIntegration(void)
{
}
```

The following image is from Object Browser in Visual Studio, after adding the .tlb to it. Maybe this helps to better understand how things are arranged inside the DLL.
[image: Screenshot from Object Browser]

Please bear in mind that this is a qustion from someone who doesn't even know the correct syntax to include the integration object into the project, so the answer may be way less complex than you may assume - it would probably be enough to just provide a short code sample that I can use as a template to start from. On the other hand, "just use #import" as an answer would not help me much because I don't know how to use it ;-)

Thanks in advance

Patrick

Comment: Use the compiler's #import directive.  It decompiles the type library into friendly C++ smart pointer wrapper classes that take care of reference counting and convert error codes to C++ exceptions.  No ATL required.  Start reading about it from the MSDN article for #import.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I had seen this article before and did now read it again but I obviously miss the essential point. After the compiler has created these files, do have to add these files to the project? And when this is done, do I then just a `#include AgentIntegration.tlh` below my `#import` statement in order to use the classes? I'll give it a try, and I will also follow some more of the links from the #import article to see where they lead me. If you copy your comment to an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: None of that is necessary, just #import.  It already automatically #includes the files.  Just look at them, there will be a .tlh and a .tli file in the build directory.  Try to understand their content.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm making progress. In the beginning didn't realize that `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF` creates a new type `IMyInterfacePtr` instead of reusing the interfaces name, and then stumbled upon the classes being declared as `struct ... IMyInterface`. I think I now have started to understand, as I managed to call the `Initialize()` method of `IAgentClient`. The next hurdle will be to implement the event handlers from `IAgentEventPtr`. I suppose that I will have to create a derived class, overriding the handler methods. Can you give me another hint on what to read or whether I'm totally wrong?

Comment: You can handle events by implementing a sink with ATL's `IDispEventImpl` class in your client. [Here's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194179) a good tutorial on how to get started.

Comment: @Aurora: Thanks very much for this link. I've learned a lot from it and have started to implement my event sink.